# Devise Action Before Destroy_User_Session_Path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise, cart

When a user clicks 'logout', my app is running destroy_user_session_path and it works great. However, I need to run the destroy method from my carts_controller before destroy_user_session_path takes place. What is the best way to run these two actions when the logout button is clicked? (I can't find the devise controller or sessionscontroller in the application)

application.html.erb - Destroy call for logout button

```
<%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, :class => 'navbar-link boldLinks btn btn-primary'  %>
```

carts/show.html.erb - Remove/empty cart call needed for before destroy when one button is clicked

```
<%= link_to 'Empty Cart', @cart, method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure you want to empty your cart?'}, :class => 'btn btn-danger whiteText' %>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can extend devise SessionsController with this way.

#### Edited answer:

create subclass devise sessions controllers, first tell Devise in routes.rb that you'd like to use your own sessions controller:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: 'users/sessions' }
```

and create one file in your controller for example **sessions_controller.rb**

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  before_action :destroy_cart, only: :destroy

  def destroy_cart
    # your command here
  end
end
```

[this link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/aa3f64976fd886b25e40dfc6043aa7b151145f94/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb#L20) is the class that we want to use

Comment: Do I create a new controller in the app/controllers folder or is there somewhere else this needs to go?

Comment: You need to have `sessions_controller.rb` file in your `/app/controller/users` folder.